# Math Roadmap / Progression

Tags: linear-algebra, physics

Apologies if this has been asked before. I am attempting to teach myself and I am currently in college. What is the roadmap for say highschool math (no AP classes) to college physics 1 and 2? Example: Basic math > Geometry > Algebra > College Algebra > Precalculus Algebra > Calculus 1 & 2 etc etc

Assuming the person knows nothing higher than highschool math.

I'm asking because I am using an online course that isn't exactly structured in a linear path and I don't know which to choose first.

Thanks

Comment: If it's calculus-based physics, you should begin with a first course in college algebra. In fact, that's where you should begin no matter what.

Comment: I have taken everything up to Precalculus Algebra. which I'll be taking this fall. It will be Calculus based physics as I will be doing premed and will need calc 1&2, orgo 1&2 and bio chem + physics 1&2. I just want to set myself up for success by trying to teach myself now.. thanks for replying